# Unity GitHub Desktop fatal: Unable to process path

Tags: unity3d, github

1. Создаю репозиторий
2. Создаю Unity проект с путем в этот репозиторий
3. Делаю initial commit но если проект открыт в Unity, выдается ошибка: "fatal: Unable to process path Unity-test-programming/Temp/FSTimeGet-26d654afe26a05c4a811d64bfff0e57c"
4. При переходе между ветками репозитория возникает такая-же ошибка, что я делаю не так? неужели нужно постоянно выходить из редактора Unity чтобы сделать commit?

Answer (score 0):

Решено: внес изменения в файл .gitignore репозитория, (убрав косую черту с необходимых исключений дабы они заработали)